# Https Nginx with Apache on :8080

Tags: nginx, https

I don't know if it is a dumb question. However, i got a debian server with nginx listening on port 80, nginx also forward all non-static content to apache2 running on 127.0.0.1:8080

I want my site run with https, i must configure only SSl of nginx?

Comment: What's the point having apache behind nginx ?

Comment: @Xavier Lucas because it's a common HA practice to have nginx in front for caching purposes and static content delivery and proxy_pass-ing only dynamic-content requests. For example nginx will require less resources to server an html file then an Apache one.

Comment: @Glueon Well, no. In this case you proxy_pass or fastcgi_pass to what's producing dynamic stuff directly. There's absolutely no logical reason to do that. It's like putting a ferrari on a truck and saying it will be faster/more robust. Loadbalance your nginx servers with keepalived/HAproxy or anything but put apache out of the chain.

Comment: I proxy_pass, is a bad thing?

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that standalone Apache will give a better performance then nginx serving static content and proxy_passing it to Apache? Well, that's wrong. If you have only one dynamic page, then maybe nginx will add just an overhead with no reason but if your start adding more and more static content this overhead will be compensated. It's taken from own experience. There are also articles about this.

Comment: Nginx is the asynchronous server. In a process-based server, each simultaneous connection requires a thread which incurs significant overhead. An asynchronous server, on the other hand, is event-driven and handles requests in a single (or at least, very few) threads. While in same condition Apache consume far too much RAM which significantly degrades performance.

Comment: Ok then what are saying that the case when nginx only does proxy_pass to Apache is a nonsense then ... It's not completely true too :) In high concurrency situation server will actually work better having Apache behind nginx. I think because of better memory consumption because requests will be queued in nginx which is better. But i afraid i can't provide you with the article which has such benchmarks. If I am wrong you may give some technical info. Ferari-truck examples do not help.

Comment: OK, however i haven't understand if work with apache and nginx together is a good practice..

Comment: @Naramsim In a nutshell : it's not. If you have enough knowledge to use it as a reverse proxy already, don't limit your business performances with such a setup and replace apache with nginx. It will be faster, be more robust and cost less as it has very low system resources usage. On top of nginx put a loadbalancing solution like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) or [Keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/).

Comment: I think you all are talking past each other. The point is, it's more efficient to simply run nginx - PHP, instead of nginx - Apache - PHP. And as far as I can tell, you both agree on this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it's ok to pass plain HTTP traffic from your nginx to the Apache server. That also has a fancy name "SSL Termination".

You can have look at this documentation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing-with-ssl-termination

If nginx and apache are both on the same machine there are almost none security reasons you shouldn't use SSL termination. Moreover that'll help to take some SSL related load off from your Apache server.